# What differences do these HTTP 3xx status codes have?

Tags: http, redirect

I was reading [the specification about HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) redirection codes. I have many questions:

1. There's a text like this:

   ```
   If the 301/302/307 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.
   ```

   **Q**: In what sense is this applied by browsers? I never saw any 301/302 response making my browser ask me if I wanted to confirm the operation (example: receiving a form by PHP and then redirecting to a new output).
2. It's clear to me that most of the times we Process-and-Redirect using a 302, instead of 303 (See other - which was created for exactly THAT purpose). However, I'm confused about 301 302 (**please note**: the intended, original behavior) and 307. **Q**: What are the differences between them in a practical example / use case?

Comment: RFC 2616 is obsolete. Please read RFC 7231 and see what changed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do all the browsers and CURL-like libraries obey the 7231?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most 301/302 redirect responses occur on regular GET requests (as opposed to POST requests) so there is no confirmation needed. Also, even though confirmation for non GET/HEAD requests is technically recommended by the RFC, the RFC also mentions that:

```
Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed to change the method on the redirected request. However, most existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303 response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which kind of reaction is expected of the client.
```

302 tells the user agent to continue using the old uri in future requests. 303 tells the user agent to use the new uri in future requests.

In addition, as the note in the RFC you link to mentions:

```
Note: Many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not understand the 303
      status. When interoperability with such clients is a concern, the
      302 status code may be used instead, since most user agents react
      to a 302 response as described here for 303.
```

I'd argue that the RFC should be changed so that `If the 301/302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.`

Should be rewritten as `If the 301/302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent SHOULD NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.`

Since otherwise most current user agent are violating the RFC.

Comment: I don't think 303 tells the user agent to use the new uri in future reqs: `The new URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested resource.`

Additionally: what's the difference between 302 (original behavior) and 307?

Comment: 302 and 307 specifically say `the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests` I took the lack of that statement and the `SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource` for the 303 code to mean we should use that uri in future reqs, though I agree that is not made explicit as written. 302 redirects on most user agents will change the request method to GET from POST. 307s do not exhibit this behavior, however 307s may not work on pre HTTP/1.1 user agents.